# Displaying a tempfile image in a Flask HTML template?

Tags: python, html, flask, qr-code, temporary-files

I'm trying to make a Two-Factor Authentication System and I want to display a QR code on the registration page for users to scan, then delete the image right after.

Here's what i've come up with so far:

```
@app.route('/register', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png", dir="static/images") as qrimg:
        form = RegisterForm(request.form)

        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data
        twofactorpass = form.twofactor.data

        twofactor = pyotp.random_base32()
        twofactorkey = pyotp.TOTP(twofactor)
        qrstring = twofactorkey.provisioning_uri(name='x', issuer_name="x")
        qr = qrcode.make(qrstring)
    
        qr.save(qrimg)

        if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():        
            if twofactorpass == twofactorkey.now():
                return redirect(url_for("register"))
            else:
                return redirect(url_for("register"))

        return render_template("register.html", form = form, img = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(qrimg.name)))
```

My problem now is that the tempfile deletes itself before the HTML is rendered, but as far as I know the "return render_template()" part has to be at the end.

So is there any way I can close the tempfile after the HTML is rendered? I'm open to any suggestions, since i'm guessing there's better ways to do this.

Comment: convert image to `base64 string` and put it directly in `<img src="base64 string">`

Comment: if you want to use files then don't use `tempfile` for this but normal file and delete it after registration.

Comment: did you try to use it in normal way - without `with ... as qrimg:`  but `qrimg = ...` - but then you will have to delete file on your own (so you would have to keep its name in cookies and use it after registration to delete file)

Comment: similar example with `base64 image`: [Flask: How to use BytesIO in Flask to display matplotlib image without saving in file.](https://blog.furas.pl/python-flask-how-to-use-bytesio-in-flask-to-display-matplotlib-image-without-saving-in-file-gb.html)